# How to change a variable value by 10 which is defined in parent component and accessed in child component using button?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular10, stackblitz

I am trying to write an application and I don't know how to change a variable value that is defined in parent component and accessed in child component.

Below is the code for child component:

This is the child component HTML markup:

```
   <p>Child Component Works!</p>
   <h2>{{name.name1}}</h2>
   <h4>{{name.Money1}}</h4>
    <h2>{{name.name2}}</h2>
   <h4>{{name.Money2}}</h4>
```

Child component Typescript code:

```
    import { Component, EventEmitter,  OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";

   @Component({
        selector: 'app-child-component',
        templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.css']
   })
   export class ChildComponentComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() name;

      constructor() { }
 
      ngOnInit() {
      }
  }
```

`Parent-component.html` markup:

```
 <p>
  Parent Component
  </p>
  <app-child-component [name]="data"></app-child-component>
  <button>
  Send Money To Jack
  </button><br><br>
  
  <button>
  Send Money To Jill
  </button>
```

`Parent-component.ts` code:

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
      selector: 'app-parent-component',
      templateUrl: './parent-component.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./parent-component.component.css']
   })
   export class ParentComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  
      data = {
         name1:'jack',
         Money1:10,
         name2:'Jill',
         Money2:'15'
      }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  }
```

This is the whole code. And below is the screenshot of output:

This is the output. I want some function that when user clicks on 1st Button then money1 variable gets incremented by 10 and when user clicks on second button then money2 variable gets incremented by 10:

[image: Output]

Comment: Have you tried to do exact the thing you've just described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That structure for displaying the data is not too good, and the scenario is somewhat sketchy, but if you're not going to change things atm, here you are:

add click functions to buttons:

```
<button (click)="incrementJack()">Send Money To Jack</button>

<button (click)="incrementJill()">Send Money To Jill</button>
```

define them in parent ts:

```
  incrementJack(){
    this.data.Money1 += 10;
  }

  incrementJill(){
    let amount = parseInt(this.data.Money2) + 10;
    this.data.Money2 = amount.toString();
  }
```

Note that the money1 is number and money2 is a string, so this cod is keeping their types.

Comment: Also, note that by provided code, buttons are part of parent, not child.